# Booting Linux from USB 3.0 External Hard Drive

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, linux-mint, usb-3

When I boot my computer, in the boot manager, I have the option to click "Windows 7" (my default OS).

When my External Hard Drive is plugged in to USB 2.0, it boots Linux (when I click on "Windows 7").

When my External Hard Drive is plugged in to USB 3.0, it boots Windows 7 (probably because it does not recognize the hard drive in USB 3.0). It does not give me an option to boot from it in the bios in USB 2.0 or 3.0 either.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it recognize USB 3.0, because I think it may be part of a bigger problem that I am trying to solve.